# SP2007: Download document after form submittal?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a request from a client to see if the following can be done.  The catch though, is we CANNOT develop any custom webparts nor use sharepoint designer.  We can only use & modify "out of the box" sharepoint webparts.

Here's the request:
We'll have a document library of images.  If the user clicks the link on an image, they're redirected to a form to fill out.  Once the form is submitted, they can then download the image they originally clicked.

Can this be done using only out of the box sharepoint 2007 features?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Robert said it's not possible to do it entirely using Out of box components, however I think you can use JavaScript to capture click events on your picture library and then forward user to a form (which you definitely will need to fill not sure what form will be for and whether it will save data any where) but then you can few code to that form save button to let user download picture or document automatically or by checking a box on form.

JavaScript will be stored in Content Editor Web-part.

Answer (score 1):

Not without some customizations (Read custom code).

Like a new webpart listing the images and does some magic on clicking of an item, or maybee a custom event receiver that triggers some workflow